# Log Grails Pre 3.0 startup time

Tags: grails

In Grails 2.x.x is it somehow possible to log the startup time? We are currently trying to optimize the application startup and having the startup time logged would help tremendously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
grails -Dgrails.script.profile=true
```

Although it may require not using forked mode. Otherwise you will need to configure logging with time stamps for the org.codehaus.groovy.grails package.